# How to scan a thing from a iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ocr

i want to know how to scan a paper from a iphone cam and i need to read the data on the paper later i want to store the data...

is it possible..?

please give me a thought...

Thanks..

Comment: You might want to add OCR to the tags

Comment: thanks Relkin...can u please give any additional info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it it very much possible.
I am not sure really how do it, but you should definitly have a look at OCR.

Try to get a look at Google Googles in the official Google iPhone app, this can actually read text off a picture you take, even at an angle.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this, http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/example-tesseract-optical-character-recognition-ocr-demo-with-source/ i've not tried the example yet, but i'm going to do that, i hope will help you.

Regards.